# Is there a way to pull analyst recommendations from Bloomberg into Python using pdblp package?

Tags: python, api, bloomberg

I am able to pull in prices:

```
import pdblp
con = pdblp.BCon()
con.start()
start_date = '20220101'
end_date = '20220701'
aapl = con.bdh(['AAPL US Equity'],['PX_LAST'],start_date,end_date) # pull generic prices
```

But when I look at ANR function within AAPL I can see a chart with 12M Tgt Px and other data on Buy Holds and Sell bar graph. Is there a way to pull this data using the API? I guess I would need to have the 12M Tgt Px as its own 'Security' so I can call PX_LAST on it unless there is another parameter in con.bdh that I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: That would be a different field than px_last. On a terminal, you can type `AAPL US Equity FLDS TARGET` to see a list of field containing the word target. Or you can ask the help desk by pressing F1 twice.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of FLDS in Bbg but in the form of code to pull it how would it look like?

Comment: I tried replacing PX_LAST with BEST_TARGET_PRICE which is one of the FLDS but code didn’t run

Comment: Fwiw, `BEST_TARGET_PRICE` works for me for `AAPL US`, when using `xbbg`. If your `PX_LAST` code worked (and returned data) then double-check you don't have a typo when you switch for `BEST_TARGET_PRICE`. Better still, put them in the same call: `['PX_LAST','BEST_TARGET_PRICE']`